# chrome extension popup.html showing up as text

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I followed [google's extension tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/) to the letter but I'm getting this weird problem where my popup.html is showing up as text instead of as an HTML page.

This is how my Popup looks.

[image]

this is my manifest.json code (same as the tutorial):

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my popup.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like either a bug in Chrome or a problem with copypasting e.g. you've used an editor like Microsoft Word. Edit the file in notepad or another pure text editor.

Comment: @kelo Are you able to reproduce it?